# JSTL Formatting: Confusing IllegalargumentException

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have an object *formatobject* in session scope, with a member of type SimpleDateFormat sdf based on a pattern "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss".

I want to use the JSTL formatting tag library to format my output:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${dataobject.date}" pattern="${formatobject.sdf}"/>
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'j'
```

When I try the following, it works as expected:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${dataobject.date} pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>
```

Confusing ... do you have an idea?

Comment: So, the `${formatobject.sdf}` *actually* returns an instance of `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` object constructed around the pattern instead of a plain `java.lang.String` representing the pattern as required by the `pattern` attribute? Why?

Comment: but shouldn't ${object} try to invoke toString()?

Comment: Uhm, it does. What do you see when you do `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`? Just don't try to do things different than documented and fix that `getSdf()` to return a `String` representing the pattern instead of `SimpleDateFormat` or just add another `getPattern()` getter returning the right thing.

Comment: argh, I see. toString() gives me the object. thought it would give me the pattern instead. since I am unable to invoke methods, there is no way to access this property. bad :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute has to refer a `String` representing the pattern, not a concrete `SimpleDateFormat` instance constructed around the pattern.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, `SimpleDateFormat` is **not** threadsafe, yet your attempt implies that it's been created in constructor of `formatobject` and reused session/application wide. This is not right. The `SimpleDateFormat` must be declared and created on a thread local basis (i.e. inside the method block). The pattern is the only part which can be a constant.

So, all with all, this is right:

```
public class Formatter {

    private static final String PATTERN = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    public String format(Date date) { // Just an example. No idea how you're further using it.
        return new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN).format(date); // Always create SimpleDateFormat in method local scope. Never create it as instance variable.
    }

    public String getPattern() {
        return PATTERN;
    }

}
```

with

```
<fmt:formatDate ... pattern="#{formatter.pattern}" />
```

Comment: thanks for your hint. but doesn't the enterprise environment's container management ensure thread-safety?

Comment: Oh sure, on HTTP servlet requests, EJB service calls, JPA transactions, etc yes, but it has absolutely no control over threadsafety of **your own** code. The `SimpleDateFormat` class is by itself simply not designed to be used across multiple threads. You're the one who's responsible for that. See also "Synchronization" section of [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).